# ¿Cómo especificar un formato al comando `get-date` de Powershell para obtener la zona horaria?

Tags: powershell

Me gustaría saber como obtengo a través de la PowerShell de Windows 10 la fecha y la hora con la zona horaria, se que es con el comando `get-date` pero no se que opción tengo que usar. Si me pueden ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Este comando hace justo lo que necesitas:**

```
((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z'))
```

Simplemente le da un formato a Get-Date y la z al final es la zona horaria. Puedes encontrar más información en esta [documentación](https://craigforrester.com/posts/convert-times-between-time-zones-with-powershell/).

---

**También puedes usar este otro comando para visualizar una lista completa con todas las zonas horarias:**

```
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::GetSystemTimeZones()
```